# Possible to name table from value from a field of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to name a table from a value from a column of a different table.

**Example**:

```
Select a from dbo.[(select x of dbo.food where x=Candy)]
```

Other Table: `dbo.Food`

```
  X      Y       Z 
--------------------
Candy  Apples  Pears
--------------------
```

I am trying to append the value from another table as a new table `dbo.candy`

Comment: you want to select a table name from another table for your query?

Comment: I want to name the table from a value from another table.

Comment: i think you need get table name dynamically in your query

Comment: This requires dynamic sql. But the bigger issue to me is this is a sign that the design of this database has gone very wrong somewhere along the way. Once you have to store the name of the table to find data you need to stop and rethink what you are doing because this is going to be painful to work with in the long run.

Comment: @SeanLange - I am trying create a tablename from a value from another column of a table.

Comment: This is a huge red flag that something is not designed well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for `select into`

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.candy
FROM dbo.food;
WHERE x = 'Candy';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_executesql` with output parameter, like this:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @tableName = select x from dbo.food where x = 'Candy';
SET @command = 'select @tempResult = a from dbo.' + @tableName;

exec sp_executesql @command , N'@tempResult NVARCHAR(MAX) out', @result out;

select @result as 'a';
```

Comment: @Jeff this is helpful for you?